# How to disable edit function when database signed=1 in php

Tags: php, mysql

if I want to disable the edit when database signed=1, how to change it?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `works` WHERE status='1' LIMIT $offset, $total_records_per_page");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$tunnelfee = get_tunnelfee($con , $row["tunnel_fee"]);
$claim = get_claim($con , $row["claim"]);
    echo "<tbody id=myTable><tr>

          <td>".$row['work_id']."</td>
          <td>".date("h:i A", strtotime($row['arrival_time']))."</td>
          <td>".$row['total_working_hours']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['fee']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$tunnelfee."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['other_fee']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['total_fee']."</td>
          <td>".$claim."</td>
          <td><a href=".$rootDir."invoice/editinvoice.php?id=".$row['id']."><img src=".$rootDir."img/edit.png width=30 height=30></a> <a href=".$rootDir."invoice/view.php?id=".$row['id']."><img src=".$rootDir."img/view.png width=30 height=30></a></td>
          </tr></tbody>";
    }
mysqli_close($con);
```

Thank you.

Comment: the script you write is not about registration/edit , edit the question with more debug info or more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the condition if ($row['signed'] !=1){ .... } so that the system can allow editing (or not)

Hence Change

```
echo "<tbody id=myTable><tr>

          <td>".$row['work_id']."</td>
          <td>".date("h:i A", strtotime($row['arrival_time']))."</td>
          <td>".$row['total_working_hours']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['fee']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$tunnelfee."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['other_fee']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['total_fee']."</td>
          <td>".$claim."</td>
          <td><a href=".$rootDir."invoice/editinvoice.php?id=".$row['id']."><img src=".$rootDir."img/edit.png width=30 height=30></a> <a href=".$rootDir."invoice/view.php?id=".$row['id']."><img src=".$rootDir."img/view.png width=30 height=30></a></td>
          </tr></tbody>";
    }
```

to

```
echo "<tbody id=myTable><tr>

          <td>".$row['work_id']."</td>
          <td>".date("h:i A", strtotime($row['arrival_time']))."</td>
          <td>".$row['total_working_hours']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['fee']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$tunnelfee."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['other_fee']."</td>
          <td>HKD ".$row['total_fee']."</td>
          <td>".$claim."</td>";

if ($row['signed'] !=1){
echo "<td><a href=".$rootDir."invoice/editinvoice.php?id=".$row['id']."><img src=".$rootDir."img/edit.png width=30 height=30></a> 
<a href=".$rootDir."invoice/view.php?id=".$row['id']."><img src=".$rootDir."img/view.png width=30 height=30></a></td> ";
} else {
echo "<td><a href=javascript:alert('Already_Signed');><img src=".$rootDir."img/edit.png width=30 height=30></a> 
<a href=".$rootDir."invoice/view.php?id=".$row['id']."><img src=".$rootDir."img/view.png width=30 height=30></a></td> ";
}

echo "</tr></tbody>";
    }
```